# How to use keywords as enum constants

Tags: java, enums

I write

```
   public class Vehicle {
        public enum condition {new, used, wrecked, rebuilt, restored};
    }
```

and it doesn't build because **new** is a keyword. I can change it to

```
public enum condition {newVehicle, used, wrecked, rebuilt, restored};
```

but that's clunky. Is there a way to use a keyword as an enum constant?

Comment: You can use `NEW`. And btw it is a standard naming convention to write enum constant as upper case letters.

Answer (score 5):

Well.. You can use upper-cased enum constants

```
public enum Condition {
  NEW, USED, WRECKED, REBUILT, RESTORED;
};
```

Also, if you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), it says

> Because they are constants, the names of an enum type's fields are in uppercase letters.

Thus, even the recommendation is to name them so.

Comment: You SHOULD, or even MUST, to be more precise.

Comment: @tworogue Added link to documentation regd that

Comment: The enum class should be capitalized as well.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart No, only the first letter of the enum class name should be capitalized.

Comment: @DorianGray Capitalized != Uppercase ;)

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Oh, I see. My bad.